# Laravel Login and Register Validation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication

Hi thank you for stopping by i'm very new to this framework and assigned to help a fellow to develop login and register.

ok here's my problem i have 2 major issues with laravel 1st login and 2nd register validation.

so i got this laravel program that already includes template for their view and only need to work for login and register part but, for the login and register i do realize it is the same flow (in controller at least as the laravel already provided but for somehow it doesn't work ).

ok let me **show my code 1st for the login part**

here's view of my login

```
             <div class="card-body">
                                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                                    @csrf
                                    <!-- @csrf_field -->
                                        <div class="form-head">
                                            <!-- <a href="{{url('/')}}" class="logo"><img src="assets/images/logo_tmu.jpeg" class="img-fluid" alt="logo"></a> -->
                                            <img src="assets/images/logo_tmu.jpeg" class="img-fluid" alt="logo">

                                        </div>                                        
                                        <h4 class="text-primary my-4">Log in !</h4>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username here" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password here" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-row mb-3">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox text-left">
                                                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="rememberme">
                                                  <label class="custom-control-label font-14" for="rememberme">Remember Me</label>
                                                </div>                                
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                              <div class="forgot-psw"> 
                                                <a id="forgot-psw" href="{{url('/user-forgotpsw')}}" class="font-14">Forgot Password?</a>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                          
                                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block font-18">Log in</button>
                                    </form>
                                    <div class="login-or">
                                        <h6 class="text-muted">OR</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- <div class="social-login text-center">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary-rgba font-18"><i class="mdi mdi-facebook mr-2"></i>Facebook</button>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger-rgba font-18"><i class="mdi mdi-google mr-2"></i>Google</button>
                                    </div> -->
                                    <!-- <p class="mb-0 mt-3">Don't have a account? <a href="{{url('/user-register')}}">Sign up</a></p> -->
                                </div>
```

middleware authenticate

```
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

redirectifauthenticate

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return view('index');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

at redirect authenticate i decided to render my main page if the login is confirm

**my issues here every time i log in and input my email and password even though i already input correctly nothing happens just like the program unable to validate the login.**

oke 2nd Register Authentication

so as i explain before the overall flow were mostly the same as the laravel auth that laravel already provided.

here's my register user controller

```
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(Request $request)
    {

        $data = [ 'name'=>$request['user'], 'email'=>$request['email'], 'password'=>$request['password']];

        validator($data);

        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

if you guys did notice that the structure were little bit different with the standart auth from laravel it is because after testing and trying i did found that i cannot pass array $data in the create function parameter because it is doesn't exist.

so i improvised and create the variable and stated or fill the data as intended to,
i tried to call the validator function before executing create, but it doesnt work and just pass directly to create somehow the validation does not work.

thank you for stopping by i do hope, you guys can help and please do gives me feedback and input thanks :)

Comment: To make things easier, what's unique about your login requirements for why you don't just use the default Laravel login and registration which requires you to write your own code?

Answer (score 0):

Your creating a validator instance but you are not checking to see if it passes our fails.

```
protected function create(Request $request) { 
    $data = [ 'name'=>$request['user'],
         'email'=>$request['email'],
         'password'=>$request['password']
    ]; 
    $validator = validator($data); 
    if($validator->fails()){
        return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
    return User::create([ 'name' => $data['name'], 'email' => $data['email'], 'password' => Hash::make($data['password']), ]); 
}
```

Comment: hi, i tried this unfortunetly it doesnt work i tried to send password that in length less than it required but it still passing the data and create in my database though